# OOM error when running gremlin queries asynchronously with JAVA

Tags: java, out-of-memory, gremlin, janusgraph, tinkerpop3

We have created a rest API that executes a gremlin query on the Janus graph and returns the result in JSON format. API works file for small result sets. But for large result sets, when we hit the API asynchronously, it gives the following error, (max heap size `-Xmx4g`

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

I am using curl with `&` to hit API asynchronously,

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://HOST:PORT/graph/search?gremlin=query &
curl --location --request GET 'http://HOST:PORT/graph/search?gremlin=query &
curl --location --request GET 'http://HOST:PORT/graph/search?gremlin=query &
curl --location --request GET 'http://HOST:PORT/graph/search?gremlin=query &
```

Code to connect to janus graph,

```
cluster = Cluster.open(config);
connect = cluster.connect();

submit = connect.submit(gremlin);
Iterator<Result> resultIterator = submit.iterator();
int count=0;
while (resultIterator.hasNext()){
    //add to list, commented to check OOM error
}
```

Configurations,

```
config.setProperty("connectionPool.maxContentLength", "50000000");
config.setProperty("connectionPool.maxInProcessPerConnection", "30");
config.setProperty("connectionPool.maxInProcessPerConnection", "30");
config.setProperty("connectionPool.maxSize", "30");
config.setProperty("connectionPool.minSize", "1");
config.setProperty("connectionPool.resultIterationBatchSize", "200");
```

Gremlin driver,

```
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin-driver:3.4.6
```

**How to handle large resultset like a cursor so that not all the data is loaded in the memory?**
Is there any configuration that I am missing? Highly appreciate any help.

Gremlin query:

```
g.withSack(0).V().hasLabel(%27material%27).has(%27dim_batchid%27,within(5028245,5080395,5366265,5159380,4872924,5093856,5216023,5068771,5093820,5154387,4703406,4872835,5214752,4893085,4866319,4556751,5342365,5075448,5074467,4835525,4987972,5347712,4986643,5204689,4755232,5076490,5028246,4922387,4659627,4597456,4743346,5080956,5370167,5260125,5134845,4613324,4720631,4937766,5356972,5148510,5210986,4930135,4984021,4720172,5028031,4836893,5068621,5333830,5020806,5081693,4988567,4869467,4709219,4958246,5021639,4607913,4923487,4614485,5066054,4869093,5339365,5204715,4980349,5215913,5342616,4959705,4959549,4929369,5022805,4920163,5204563,5027627,5208788,4712451,4862298,5019103,4982159,4727160,5395618,4924536,5390450,4943986,5071744,5208844,4898192,5347546,5204875,4710474,4794222,4962808,5269053,4836267,4602886,5359126,5393203,4780380,5148475,5092749,5351705,5339311,4601782,4869039,5366475,4959070,4963475,5346888,4923494,5279816,5297980,5154181,5030501,5142954,5392329,4839306,4890656,5134911,4893104,4989444,5069672,4961009,5027559,5029007,5285813,4820025,5287707,4959634,5148474,5362926,5362211,4557278,5353486,4933573,4785560,4890658,4930937,4553089,5030503,5341503,4783801,5068529,4821152,5208845,4766406,5043752,4770709,4733416,5204713,4815450,4981053,4963427,4980830,5340154,4771353,5204561,4920161,4794149,5275867,5021788,5364102,5205411,5356459,4794233,4923438,4610509,5392350,4746342,5022804,4936411,5361555,4890888,4980829,4959869,4869092,4891157,4815449,5267434,4836975,4684010,5281322,5071746,4711290,5289333,5021638,5299283,5210803,5348731,5068491,4776862,5196532,4766677,4930133,5210984,4608878,5261295,4826630,4786051,4779996,4930134,5020804,4766678,4869064,5286802,4545299,4693065,4930844,4816538,4888415,4711706,4923002,4780402,5044968,5148437,4753993,5074466,4890805,5074558,5076491,4547035,5092021,5262308,5205445,5213382,5159381,5263280,5351407,4890706,4659738,5344469,5075928,4613336,5065866,4863764,5217111,4792255,5210914,5204691,4890806,5148438,4986897,4817686,4712337,5196528,5280266,4929327,5134843,5393007,5019151,4923482,4763007,4929395)).emit().repeat(sack(sum).by(constant(1)).inE().outV()).project(%27level%27,%27properties%27).by(sack()).by(tree().by(valueMap().by(fold().unfold())).by(valueMap().by(fold())))
```

From profiling, it is clear that the gremlin driver is causing the issue but I am not sure how to fix it and release the memory.
[image]

Also, the threads go into a frozen state for more than 5 mins,

[image]

Comment: Does Gremlin Server produce the OOM or your REST API? Also, it looks like you are submitting a Gremlin script - you might need to share that query.

Comment: REST API is causing OOM when it hit the API asynchronously. The issue is here `while (resultIterator.hasNext())` . The query returns a large dataset which is causing this to wait for all results to complete.

Comment: @stephenmallette I have added the query in the question.

Comment: the comment in that loop says "//add to list, commented to check OOM error" - are you actually building a `List` object with each result?

Comment: I was building but commented that code to check if adding to the list was causing the OOM but it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it is possible that you are running into this issue [TINKERPOP-2424](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2424). Basically the queue that holds the incoming results is filling faster than you can consume the results and you blow the heap. You can see that there is a patch there that in the issue that seems to solve the problem but I'm not convinced that it's the best solution just yet so it hasn't be implemented. If you have suggestions for how to resolve the problem, please feel free to comment on the ticket. If that is not the issue you are facing I think you'd have to provide a way to replicate your problem or do some profiling to isolate your issue further. Perhaps it would be good to do some profiling anyway as you should be able to prove that TINKERPOP-2424 is your problem that way. If you have a look at the [mailing list link](https://groups.google.com/g/gremlin-users/c/I4HQC9JkzSo/m/fYfd5o0UAQAJ) in that post you should see the approach taken to verify the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have done the profiling and it seems the issue is with gremlin driver. I have added the screenshots of profiling.

Comment: I don't think it's related to queue filling faster than can be consumed as I tried doing nothing while iterating.

Comment: in my testing i saw that just iterating with no processing of the result doesn't empty the queue fast enough for GC to catch up. it's a little weird to think about - didn't believe it until i saw it for myself actually

Comment: The issue only when we run the queries asynchronously. It works for single query execution. But even for a single query, it does not release all the heap memory.